# Emacs batch mode doesn't recognize org files in osx

Tags: macos, csv, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to use emacs -batch to create a csv file that shows all the todo items in my org-mode file. It works great on my linux box, but I can't get it to work in OSX.

Here is the command I am using:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs org-mode -eval '(org-batch-agenda-csv "t")'
```

OSX doesn't recognize org-batch-agenda-csv, but it will recognize a non-csv version:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs org-mode -eval '(org-batch-agenda "t")'
```

However, this still doesn't work. It comes back with the following response:

```
Agenda file ~/projects.org is not in `org-mode'
```

I think I have narrowed down the root problem. Emacs and emacs as opened by the terminal work differently. Emacs will autorecognize my org files, but if I open them in the terminal, emacs will start in fundamental mode. I think if I could get emacs terminal mode to auto-recognize org-files the problem would go away. Oddly, it doesn't seem to have trouble auto-recognizing other file types. It is almost like it isn't actually reading my .emacs file.

I can't seem to find anything through google. Hopefully I'm not the only person who has this issue.

Appreciate any pointers you can help me with.

-- Russ

Comment: Which Emacs version are you using? Normally, on OS X "emacs" lauches Emacs 22, which doesn't have support for org mode. Instead, try to use the "Emacs" binary inside Emacs.app.

Comment: Yes! (emacs-version) show version 22 in terminal but 24 if I use it out of terminal, but it does support org-mode. I just have to manually call org-mode. It doesn't automatically recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lindydancer. So for some reason OSX terminal opens up emacs version 22 instead of version 24. The same command works great if it is called as the binary file from Applications file.

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs org-mode -eval '(org-batch-agenda "t")'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The default location for the old/outdated version of Emacs that ships with OSX is inside `/usr/bin` -- so if you call just `emacs` from the terminal, you get that one.  For convenience, you may wish to set up an *alias* command to easily call the preferred Emacs installation.